# Is there a way to hide the ID column in Keystone.js?

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I'm having troubles trying to hide the ID column, auto-generated by Keystone List template. Is there a way to suppress this column?
The documentation is pretty scant covering only basic usage of the framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ID column shows up when there isn't a "name" field that can be used to link to the details view in the Admin UI (or when the name field isn't being displayed).

You can't hide it, or rather we need *something* that can be used to attach the link to. You can, however replace it with any other `name` or `text` field using the `map` feature.

For example, if you wanted to use a `key` column as the "linking" / identifier property in your model:

```
var MyList = new keystone.List('MyList', {
  map: { name: 'key' }
});

MyList.add({
  key: String // this will be used wherever a "name" is required, instead of the ID
});
```

It's covered in the [List Options](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#lists-options) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out though.
I found out that this would do also:
MyList.mappings = { name: 'key' };

Comment: The List Options link you provided is throwing a 404.